# Audio (.wav) plays when run from jGRASP but not from Eclipse or IntellliJ IDEA

Tags: eclipse, audio, intellij-idea, jgrasp

This code works fine and plays sound in jGRASP but when it is run from a project in IDEA or Eclipse, no sound plays. How can I get this working on all the IDEs?

```
public void playClip( String clipPlay ){
    AudioClip clip = null;
    File filePlay = new File( clipPlay );

    try{
        clip = Applet.newAudioClip( filePlay.toURI().toURL() );
    }
    catch( MalformedURLException ex ){
        System.err.println( ex.getMessage() );           
    }

    clip.play();
}
```

Comment: Do you get any kind of error, from your code or IntelliJ?

Comment: No errors and no warnings. It runs and the window loads, just the sound never plays.

Comment: It's a bit tough to pin down the issue if there are no errors either from your code or the IDE.

Comment: I had only run debug in IDEA. Just ran debug in Eclipse and found FileNotFoundException. I don't know why it wasn't showing up before.